# (Unix) Display a block of Lines based on a pattern

Tags: bash, unix, sed, grep

I want to list out all the error messages in the log file as below, with the complete description of their error.

```
00:02:00:00 Here I found an ERROR
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 This is a System Error (DESCRIPTION_ENDS)
00:02:00:00 
00:02:00:00 Some General Message
00:02:00:00 Some General Message
00:02:00:00 
00:02:00:00 Again got an ERROR
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 This is a Critical Error (DESCRIPTION_ENDS)
00:02:00:00 
00:02:00:00 Some General Message
00:02:00:00 Some General Message
```

I am looking for a logic, probably using grep or sed, which will display only the ERROR block with Description.

Output :

```
00:02:00:00 Here I found an ERROR
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 This is a System Error (DESCRIPTION_ENDS)

00:02:00:00 Again got an ERROR
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 This is a Critical Error (DESCRIPTION_ENDS)
```

To achieve this, the only logic that I can think of is to read the entire file and print the lines having "ERROR" to till the line containing "DESCRIPTION_ENDS".

Can this be implemented using grep or sed ? If not, any other command in unix, by which this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

`awk` is an option:

```
awk '/ERROR/ {on=1} on==1 {print} /DESCRIPTION_ENDS/ {on=0; print ""}' data
```

**Explanation:** there are 3 rules and `awk` applies them in sequence.

- The first (`/ERROR/ {on=1}`) sets the `awk` variable `on` if the line matches the `ERROR` pattern.
- The second (`on==1 {print}`) prints the current line if the `awk` variable `on` is set.
- The third (`/DESCRIPTION_ENDS/ {on=0; print ""}`) clears the `awk` variable `on` and inserts an empty line if the line matches the `DESCRIPTION_ENDS` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk '/ERROR/{f=1};f;/(System|Critical) Error/{print "";f=0}' infile
```

Check http://klashxx.github.io/awk-between-two-patterns/ for a detailed explanation.

**Results**

```
00:02:00:00 Here I found an ERROR
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 This is a System Error (DESCRIPTION_ENDS)

00:02:00:00 Again got an ERROR
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 This is a Critical Error (DESCRIPTION_ENDS)
```

And a `sed` alternative (less flexible for my taste):

```
sed -nr '/\s+ERROR/,/\s+Error\s+\(/p' infile
```

Will output:

```
00:02:00:00 Here I found an ERROR
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 This is a System Error (DESCRIPTION_ENDS)
00:02:00:00 Again got an ERROR
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 This is a Critical Error (DESCRIPTION_ENDS)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl One-Line Solution Using Flip-Flop Range Operator

This is really just a one-liner, but it's been expanded a bit for readability. It relies on the flip-flop range operator defined in PERLOP(1) to match the start and end of your blocks in a line-oriented way. For example:

```
$ perl -ne 'print if /ERROR/.../DESCRIPTION_ENDS/;
            print "\n" if /DESCRIPTION_ENDS/;
           ' /tmp/corpus
00:02:00:00 Here I found an ERROR
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 This is a System Error (DESCRIPTION_ENDS)

00:02:00:00 Again got an ERROR
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 Description
00:02:00:00 This is a Critical Error (DESCRIPTION_ENDS)
```

The extra print statement is really just there to create paragraphs between your blocks to improve readability, and to make it more suitable for consumption by Perl, Awk, or Ruby with each language's paragraph mode turned on. This will ease further processing, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not exactly what you want (however this is much simpler), but you could try searching for the error and using the -A option for grep to provide some context.

```
grep -A 5 "ERROR" myFile
```

I realise that I've hardcoded the context to a fixed 5 lines which might not solve your problem, but if all you are doing is manually searching log files then it might be good enough.

If your descriptions have some format to them then you could pipe the result into a second grep so it only include the lines you want.

Comment: @ Stormcloud, Thanks for the information. But the problem here is, we can't expect that error message to be a fixed length. Again, if we have a huge file, we need to go through the entire file manually to check, how many lines, each block contains.

Comment: @BS  I Agree. I just wanted to quickly give you an easy to follow answer. It's possible to use a couple of piped grep commands *if* you know the maximum number of lines a description can take and all the lines in the description conform to a pattern.

If I were you I'd pick one of those awk or sed solutions as the correct answer. They are more complex but they do exactly the right thing.